# How to reset a select field onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange, use-state

I have a dropdown select component that is populated by what is selected from a set of buttons. Before a selection from the button list is made the dropdown has no choices. But I have created an issue where if a button is selected then another is selected the dropdown still holds the value from the previous selection even tho that item is not suppose to be in the list of options in the drop down. I am trying to figure out a way to reset or clear the selection:

```
const [location, setLocation] = useState("");
const [thvchecked, setThvChecked] = useState(false);
const [pvchecked, setPvChecked] = useState(false);
const [osvchecked, setOsvChecked] = useState(false);

let emCodeOptions = [];
if (location === "telehealthVisit") {
      emCodeOptions = telehealthVisitEMCode;
    } else if (location === "telephoneVisit") {
      emCodeOptions = telephoneVisitEMCodeChoices;
    } else if (location === "onSiteVisit") {
      emCodeOptions = onSiteVisitEMCodeChoices;
    } else {
      emCodeOptions = [];
    }

const handleEMCodeChange = (selected) => {
    props.onUpdate("emCode", selected.value);
  };

const onLocationSelection = (event) => {
    let loc = event.target.name;

    if (loc === "telehealthVisit") {
      setLocation("");
      setThvChecked(!thvchecked);
      props.onUpdate("visitLocation", loc);
    } else if (loc === "telephoneVisit") {
      setLocation("");
      setPvChecked(!pvchecked);
      props.onUpdate("visitLocation", loc);
    } else if (loc === "onSiteVisit") {
      setLocation("");
      setOsvChecked(!osvchecked);
      props.onUpdate("visitLocation", loc);
    }

   setLocation(loc);
  };
```

I though I could do this by resetting the state in the `onLocationSlection` function but this doesnt seem to work beyond the first time I change my selection.

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't call render method each time u setLocation . It will accumulate the values and smartly call the render with the last value. So setLocation to '' doesn't have the desired effect.

This piece of code looks logically correct to me. Are you updating arrays telehealthVisitEMCode, telephoneVisitEMCodeChoices else where?

Comment: Hmm so I should rethink how I am using `setLocation` ? I am new to developing so im following you but its not totally clear. And yes `telehealthVisitEMCode` and `telephoneVisitEMCodeChoices` and `onsiteVisitEMCodeChoices` are all arrays that update the `emCodeOptions` array when the location is selected. What i show in my code snippet is the only place where this value is changed.

Comment: I think your code is logically correct. I feel the issue might be with arrays. Are you sure that the arrays contain the correct values? You could print the arrays in the render function and check if the user interface is showing the same data.